# pixel co-ordinates for image: way to access locations on image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I wanted to ask in which range pixel coordinates for image pixel can be denoted?

Let's say I have an image of size `(100*100)`. Till now I used to access certain pixel as `int` or `float` value e.g. `(50,50) or (40,85)`.

Recently I came across the github repo, where image location is initialized as values between `(-1,1)` using following code:

`pixel_location = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1,2)).astype(np.float32)`

This is bit confusing for me, how can we access the image location using uniform distribution from range `-1` to `1`?

What things to keep in mind when my program is generating image pixel locations from range `0 - 100` which I have to feed in this github code which is using pixel locations from `-1` to `1` for the image size of `100*100`

Note about project: I need to process certain part of the image for classification task using the github repo, but I think the image location format will cause the problem here.

Comment: your code makes no sense. from where did you get it?

Comment: line 58: https://github.com/amasky/ram/blob/master/ram.py

Comment: looks like some type of normalized coordinates

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Could you explain, why does it not make sense in the location initialization?

Answer (score 0):

here if you have an image of 100x100 then, img[-1][1] will be the 1st pixel of the 99th row. you can get the result using opencv as below

```
img = cv2.imread("Test.jpg")
print(img[-1][1])
```

you will get the value of the pixel[99,1]

for more assurance you can use

```
img = cv2.imread("Test.jpg")
img[-1][1] = (0,0,255)
cv2.imwrite("Test.jpg",img)
```

pixel[99,1] will be red in Test.jpg

Comment: I am bit unclear about this, when I use: ```np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=(1,2)).astype(np.float32)```, I get float values from ```-1```  to ```1```, for example: ```array([[0.87334806, 0.6837041 ]], dtype=float32)```. I want to find mapping between this to my original method of actual location like directly using pixel coordinates ``` (50,50)``` . In your answer you are using the ```int ```values.